# IE7 JSON object being appended to basepage url

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, internet-explorer

I'm having strange IE7 behavior at the moment.  We reach out to an external service that returns a formatted JSON object back to us.  Any other version of IE can handle this object.  However in IE7, it simply appends the JSON string to the end of the basepage url.  so we end up with something like this...

```
http://localhost:1111/X?Param=223"#13988652796891&{"TestCodes":{"TestCode":.....
```

The page then takes it upon itself to refresh, and breaks because the url isn't correct.  Has anyone seen anything like this before, and if so was there something they were using that caused this to happen?  I can give a few more details, I have other issues debugging because I do not have an actual instance of IE7 on this machine. (I've been using IETester, but I can't actually step through code this way)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need http://bestiejs.github.io/json3/ to use json in IE7 if you aren't using it already.

Comment: You need to show some code...